# Docker MySQL Server Connection Issue using .env file of Laravel

Tags: laravel

My docker cmds:

```
docker volume create SQL-DB

docker run \      
  --name MySQL \
  -p 3306:3306 \
  -v SQL-DB:/var/lib/mysql \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
  -d mysql:latest
```

Able to connect via TablePLUS & other MySQL Clients. But Failed to connect using `.env` file of Laravel.

`.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=chrip
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

`chirp` DB has been created using TablePlus MySQL client.

@apokryfos after running `php artisan migrate` error is:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = chrip and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712
    708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
    713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    714▕             );
    715▕         }
    716▕     }

      +33 vendor frames 
  34  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Comment: Does your laravel application run in it's own container ? You might need a network between containers to make sure they can talk to each other.

Comment: @Nicolas laravel application run in local pc

Comment: My question was more: What are you using to run your laravel application on your local pc. Do you have a stack like wamp or laragon ? Is there a dedicated docker container for laravel ?

Comment: @Nicolas Now I'm in the development stage. Using `php artisan serve`

Comment: What's the exact error you see in Laravel?

Comment: @apokryfos error added in the question. please see the updated question

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the using of localhost ip in the .env file dbhost value. The db server is running in docker. so it behave as a separate network. So it will not be working in localhost ip. Please find the ip of the docker container. using **docker inspect** command and update .env file with the ip.

Comment: Found the ip using the cmd. But it does not work.
`docker inspect --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" b8365415d70c6db110f1a75785e55a5d888035f20fe9ddb1a213a3f9babe17fe1`

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP address is all but useless.  It's only accessible at all from one very specific Docker/host OS combination, and even then it's not a best practice to use it.

Comment: did you clear cache after the changes

Comment: No effect after clearing cache

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you run the php-laravel on local machine using `php artisan serve` and mysql runs on docker, either you add the IP of mysql container or add flag `--network host` when you run mysql container instead of port mapping. This should solve your issue

Comment: Not working. Checked your both solutions

Comment: can you provide the error after trying?

Comment: well, can you reach your DB from workbench such as mysql workbench or phpmyadmin using same url , credentials?

Comment: yes, I can access from workbench

Comment: you may want to run `php artisan optimize:clear && php artisan clear:all` so app can read new configs the try again, I hope this time works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257062/discussion-between-rajan-saha-raju-and-mohammed-ehab).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it worked for Mariadb.

Here is the docker cmd:

```
docker run --detach \
  -p 3306:3306 \
  -v sql:/var/lib/mysql \
  --name MARIA-DB \
  --env MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret-pw \
  mariadb:latest
```

And here is the `.env` file of Laravel:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=chrip
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret-pw
```